# I am getting an Empty List after my app was working before?

Tags: android, rest, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So I have finished a weather app where it was fully working a month ago. Then yesterday, I ran the app again and I ended up getting a blank screen. This app is using an API, so I checked it and the API is still available and working. Not sure why I'm getting a blank screen.

P.S. I am using Jetpack Compose

Here's the code that is causing the emptyList

Settings View Model

```
@HiltViewModel
class SettingsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: WeatherDbRepository
): ViewModel() {
    private val _unitList = MutableStateFlow<List<Unit>>(emptyList())
    val unitList = _unitList.asStateFlow()


    init {
        getUnitList()
    }

    private fun getUnitList() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.getUnits().distinctUntilChanged()
                .collect{listOfUnits ->
                    if (listOfUnits.isNullOrEmpty()){
                        Log.d("TAG", "getUnitList: Empty List")
                    }else{
                        _unitList.value = listOfUnits
                    }

                }
        }
    }


    fun insertUnit(unit: Unit) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.insertUnit(unit) }
    fun updateUnit(unit: Unit) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.updateUnit(unit) }
    fun deleteUnit(unit: Unit) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.deleteUnit(unit) }
    fun deleteAllUnits() = viewModelScope.launch { repository.deleteAllUnits() }

}
```

Repository

```
class WeatherDbRepository @Inject constructor(private val weatherDao: WeatherDao) {

    fun getFavorites(): Flow<List<Favorite>> = weatherDao.getFavorites()
    suspend fun insertFavorite(favorite: Favorite) = weatherDao.insertFavorite(favorite)
    suspend fun updateFavorite(favorite: Favorite) = weatherDao.updateFavorite(favorite)
    suspend fun deleteALlFavorite() = weatherDao.deleteAllFavorites()
    suspend fun deleteFavorite(favorite: Favorite) = weatherDao.deleteFavorite(favorite)
    suspend fun getFavById(city: String): Favorite = weatherDao.getFavByID(city)

    fun getUnits(): Flow<List<Unit>> = weatherDao.getUnits()
    suspend fun insertUnit(unit: Unit) = weatherDao.insertUnit(unit)
    suspend fun updateUnit(unit: Unit) = weatherDao.updateUnt(unit)
    suspend fun deleteAllUnits() = weatherDao.deleteAllUnits()
    suspend fun deleteUnit(unit: Unit) = weatherDao.deleteUnit(unit)

}
```

App Module(DI)

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideWeatherDao(weatherDatabase: WeatherDatabase): WeatherDao =
        weatherDatabase.weatherDao()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideWeatherDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): WeatherDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            WeatherDatabase::class.java,
            "weatherD"
        )
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOpenWeatherApi(): WeatherApi {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(WeatherApi::class.java)
    }

}
```

The Log (getUnitsList log is at the bottom)

```
08/07 15:03:47: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3 XL API 30.
Install successfully finished in 696 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.weatherapp/com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 3468 on device 'Pixel_3_XL_API_30 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/mple.weatherap: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I/mple.weatherap: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
W/mple.weatherap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/mple.weatherap: Class androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList failed lock verification and will run slower.
    Common causes for lock verification issues are non-optimized dex code
    and incorrect proguard optimizations.
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf2f8fa50, tid 3495
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf2f90d90: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf2f90d90: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf32f1c90) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf2f92d10, tid 3495
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3efffe000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=727ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=1214569752715, Vsync=1214653086045, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=1214662199300, AnimationStart=1214662216300, PerformTraversalsStart=1214662432500, DrawStart=1215266847200, SyncQueued=1215283423600, SyncStart=1215284670600, IssueDrawCommandsStart=1215284716800, SwapBuffers=1215296537700, FrameCompleted=1215298216000, DequeueBufferDuration=186800, QueueBufferDuration=588900, GpuCompleted=72904454231491230, 
I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/mple.weatherap: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/TAG: getUnitList: Empty List
D/ProfileInstaller: Installing profile for com.example.weatherapp
```

I'll leave my GitHub repo link for further observations. Thank You for the help
GitHub Link: https://github.com/OEThe11/WeatherApp/tree/Trials

Comment: I downloaded your application and run it. It seems to me that when it starts it does not do any network request to fetch the data.

Comment: Really, How? The setup for network request does work on my other apps. And worked on this app too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at the logic you have on the `MainScreen`.

You have not considered the fact that on a clean install of an application the Room DB is going to be empty. So you are not allowing the application to do a network request in case it cannot find the selected `unitFromDb`.

If you comment that logic it works:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    city: String?
) {
    val curCity: String = if (city!!.isBlank()) "New York" else city

    val unitFromDb = settingsViewModel.unitList.collectAsState().value
    var unit by remember {
        mutableStateOf("imperial")
    }
    var isImperial by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

//    if (unitFromDb.isNotEmpty()) {
//        unit = unitFromDb[0].unit.split(" ")[0].lowercase()
//        isImperial = unit == "imperial"
    isImperial = false

        val weatherData =
            produceState<DataOrException<GetWeatherNetworkResponse, Boolean, Exception>>(
                initialValue = DataOrException(loading = true)
            ) {
                value = viewModel.getWeatherData(
                    city = curCity,
                    units = unit
                )
            }.value

        if (weatherData.loading == true) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()

        } else if (weatherData.data != null) {
            MainScaffold(weather = weatherData.data!!, navController, isImperial = isImperial)
        }
//    }

}
```

You have to consider adding a default value in the DB if this is the first time the application starts or request from the user to select one if there is nothing selected.

> I am getting an Empty List after my app was working before?

To also answer your question. I suspect that you had done a sucessful request for the weather and you application had the offline data, so coding afterwards the faulty logic you application was working with the offline data, or it had the required value on the DB so it can request for new data from the network. Now that you did a clean install on the application with all the logic you stepped on that faulty case.

Comment: That did it. I appreciate that. But it's interesting because initially, when it worked, I had nothing in the database, so it'll just start up with the default city. I did clean and rebuild the project several times, but it never worked. Then again I have cleared my emulator data, which could explain the blank screens all of a sudden.

Comment: Clean and rebuild in android studio does not remove the application data from the device/emulator. I also test such cases with install/uninstall of the application or just "Clear app data" from the Application Info in the application manager app of the device/emulator.

Comment: Oh, so this was just a logic error that I need a clean device to find out about?

Comment: Correct! You can experiment with the commented code and find the right logic for whatever you are trying to do! My suggestion was just a quick and dirty approach to in order to allow the request to happen ;-)

Answer (score 0):

in my case rebuilding gradle again fixed the problem
also try to clear build

Comment: How did you rebuild the Gradle and how to clear build?

Comment: 1-there are many ways but I myself do that in a sort of funny way, I will delete some character from Gradle file and click on and then click on sync ,after getting the error ,I would put that character way and sync Gradle file again
2-under 'Build' tab select clean project and then rebuild project